# Crystal: TOC add dots

Tags: crystal-reports, tableofcontents

I try to add dots between the page title and the page number in Crystal Reports for a table of content. I found http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1545153&page=1 in the web, but I wonder if there's a more simple and direct way to get the same result.

I'm using CR shipping with VS 2008.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could draw a dotted line behind the page title and page number fields, bring the fields to the front, and set their backgrounds to white. It wouldn't quite be the periods you're looking for, but it's a bit less baroque than the other method.